# Converting Varbinary Data to Nvarchar in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to encrypt my password field where passwords are kept before, my table structure is :

```
Create table #table (username varchar(50),passwords nvarchar(1000))
Insert into #table values ('abc','pass_123')
```

Now I am encrypting my password like below:

```
update #table set passwords = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)  
where PATINDEX('%[a0-z9]%',passwords) > 0
```

But when I am decrypting the password with the below code:

```
Select username,convert(varchar(max),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)) as pwd from #table
```

It gives me output as

```
username  Passwords  
abc        p
```

If I change my above code like this:

```
Select username,convert(nvarchar(max),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)) as pwd from #table
```

It gives me correct output

```
username  Passwords  
abc        pass_123
```

After changing varchar to nvarchar works for the passwords which was already present, But if there is a new user and I am encrypting the password during Insert like below:

```
Insert into #table values ('abc',ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key','123'))
```

So while decrypting the records with nvarchar my data looks like:

```
Select username,convert(nvarchar(1000),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)) as pwd from #table

username    pwd
abc         pass_123
abc         ㈱3
```

If I use varchar my data will look like this:

```
Select username,convert(varchar(max),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)) as pwd from #table

username    pwd
abc         p
abc         123
```

So basically if we update the existing records nvarchar works for decryption but if we insert a new record varchar works for decryption. So what is the change I need to make to get the consistent data either by varchar or nvarchar

Comment: Try puttin an N before the new user's password literal:`Insert into #table values ('abc',ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',N'123'))`

Comment: Why are you storing passwords you can decrypt at all? If this is for an application the password should be salted and hashed, so it can't be decrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you're reading the data from a NVARCHAR field from the table. Even though the string you insert into it is VARCHAR, SQL Server will convert it for you.

However these are two different data types (one being two bytes per character the other single byte) and thus get turned into different binaries.

The functions `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` and `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` take any valid text input as valid input. In your first example you insert a VARCHAR string into a table, converting it to NVARCHAR. Then use this as input (it's NVARCHAR now). But if you insert the string directly you're denoting it as VARCHAR and thus convert it to binary in this format.

With your current table structure:

```
Insert into #table values ('abc','pass_123')
--Values inserted gets converted to NVARCHAR, even though the string 'pass_123' is VARCHAR

update #table set passwords = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)  
where PATINDEX('%[a0-z9]%',passwords) > 0
--Thus when calling the update the source string is in NVARCHAR encoding

Select username,convert(nvarchar(max),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)) as pwd from #table
--So the varbinary is based on the NVARCHAR encoding and thus only viewable when it's made nvarchar

/* This is the same as */
Insert into #table values ('abc',ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',N'123'))
--Value being provided as a parameter to ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE is already in NVARCHAR format

Select username,convert(nvarchar(1000),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Key',passwords)) as pwd from #table
--This ends up with the same result, because the varbinary was based on a NVARCHAR
```

This is purely because of your source data types, in one scenario you put in a NVARCHAR as source, in the other a VARCHAR. Which when converted give different values for the varbinary.

MSDN:

- [Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Decryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Whether this is a right approach from a security standpoint is a different question entirely.

Comment: Thank you!! for the explanation I rectified my mistake.